# How to add text over video like on Snapchat

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmediaplayercontroller

I am building a messaging app that has similar functionality as Snapchat. How would I be able to add a text over video that can be positioned anywhere in the screen and also be able to export the video with the text.

Answer (score 1):

From the tags I am guessing that you are using mpmediaplayercontroller. You cannot achieve text over video using this controller. To apply text over the video you need to use avassetplayer and take the composition of the video and apply a catextlayer to the video composition..

Follow the tutorial at [this link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos). This will definitely help you solve your problem..